# Removing -Bash errors that I got after each login

Tags: bash

I recently uninstalled an app that I used for monitoring the UPS (View Power Pro) but unfortunately it didn´t worked, and after I uninstalled the app, each time I log in to my Machine I´m getting this, any idea on how to remove it?:

```
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
[1]   Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
[2]-  Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
[3]+  Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
```

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @CarlosAndreasZapataCuervo : Run a new login shell with `bash --login -x` and deduce from the trace, which statement in your initialization files causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into your profile's .bashrc and .profile files, there must be some residual references to those files, maybe into undeleted scripts from the app you are talking about

Comment: Sorry about the delay, just navigate to your home folder (with 'cd' command is enough) and type 'vim .bashrc' or 'vim ,profile' this should open those files containing the startup script for your user at login. But be careful not to touch anything you don't recognize or you may end up breaking your user configuration. Please try to search for those files meanings over your system before modifing them